# List all active databases that are marked for replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to figure out a way to list all **active** databases that are marked for replication.

I've tried two queries that don't work:

```
select * from [distribution].[dbo].[MSpublications]
```

In this code you will see all databases that have been replicated, even though one is not replicated at the moment but it used to be.

```
select * from sys.databases 
where is_published=1 or is_subscribed=1 or is_merge_published=1
```

I'm not happy with the second query either.

Comment: What's your concern about the second query?

Comment: Well, it's not working.
I used it on a small instance and saw that database that are been replicated are not shown in this query.

Answer (score 1):

I realize your post was submitted quite a while back, but since a decent solution hasn't been provided, I thought I'd contribute everything below, in case anyone else runs into the same scenario.

1. The main issue is most likely that you lack sufficient security permissions on the new "small instance" where you can't see any results.  Once you resolve that, the code you have should work, and is probably the easiest / most-efficient approach.  From Microsoft's website:

> > **Permissions:**
> >     If the caller of sys.databases is not the owner of the database and the database is not master or tempdb, the minimum permissions required to see the corresponding row are ALTER ANY DATABASE or VIEW ANY DATABASE server-level permission, or CREATE DATABASE permission in the master database. The database to which the caller is connected can always be viewed in sys.databases.
> >     ([MSDN: permissions required to view sys.databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534(v=sql.110).aspx))

2. Another way to verify whether a given DB is published, subscribed or merge-published, is to use the DATABASEPROPERTYEX() function.  I'm including an example below, that'll pull for a single database. ([MSDN: DATABASEPROPERTYEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186823(v=sql.110).aspx))

---

```
DECLARE @db NVARCHAR(70);
SET @db = N'{database_name}'; --Insert here the name of the DB-in-question.

SELECT  @db AS [Database], 
        CASE DATABASEPROPERTYEX(@db, N'IsPublished') WHEN 1 THEN N'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS [Published], 
        CASE DATABASEPROPERTYEX(@db, N'IsSubscribed') WHEN 1 THEN N'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS [Subscribed], 
        CASE DATABASEPROPERTYEX(@db, N'IsMergePublished') WHEN 1 THEN N'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS [Merge_Published];
```

---

3. To use the above example to find for all databases on a system, simply use sp_msForEachDB, as in the below example:

### **SIMPLER APPROACH:**

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @sql = N'USE ?; 
        SELECT ''?'' AS [Database], 
        CASE DATABASEPROPERTYEX(''?'', N''IsPublished'') WHEN 1 THEN N''TRUE'' ELSE ''--'' END AS [Published], 
        CASE DATABASEPROPERTYEX(''?'', N''IsSubscribed'') WHEN 1 THEN N''TRUE'' ELSE ''--'' END AS [Subscribed], 
        CASE DATABASEPROPERTYEX(''?'', N''IsMergePublished'') WHEN 1 THEN N''TRUE'' ELSE ''--'' END AS [Merge_Published];';
EXEC sp_msForEachDB @SQL;
```

---

### **CLEANEST OUTPUT:**

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE (
    [db] NVARCHAR(70), 
    [isPublished] NVARCHAR(5), 
    [isSubscribed] NVARCHAR(5), 
    [isMergePublished] NVARCHAR(5));  

SET @sql = 
    N'IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'', ''distribution'') BEGIN 
        USE ?; 
        SELECT ''?'' AS [Database], 
        CASE DATABASEPROPERTYEX(''?'', N''IsPublished'') WHEN 1 THEN N''TRUE'' ELSE ''--'' END AS [Published], 
        CASE DATABASEPROPERTYEX(''?'', N''IsSubscribed'') WHEN 1 THEN N''TRUE'' ELSE ''--'' END AS [Subscribed], 
        CASE DATABASEPROPERTYEX(''?'', N''IsMergePublished'') WHEN 1 THEN N''TRUE'' ELSE ''--'' END AS [Merge_Published];
    END';
INSERT INTO @tbl EXEC sp_msForEachDB @SQL;
SELECT * FROM @tbl ORDER BY [db] ASC;
```

---

Answer (score -3):

exec sp_helpreplicationdboption

Comment: And what was wrong with this answer?  This stored proc is from Microsoft and when executed it lists all databases on the server along with flags to indicate that the database is enabled for replication.  Did you mean something other than that?  Do I need to post a screenshot of the output?